# Trigger -Error Invalid initial value type List<User> for Set<Id>

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

**Requirement** - Checkbox in User `NoOwner__c`. If it is checked and I am going to update account Owner then it needs to throw an error else needs to save record.

I am getting error Invalid initial value type `List<User>` for `Set<Id>`. Can someone please help me to sort this issue or any other way to write trigger for it,as I am new to trigger I have written my own way.

---

```
trigger updateOwnerID on Account (after update) {
    set<id> OwnerIds=new Set<id>();
    for (Account acc:trigger.new){
        OwnerIds.add(acc.ownerid);
    }   
    set<id> userids=new set<id>([select id from user where id in :OwnerIds and NoOwner__c=true]);
    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        if(userids.contains(acc.ownerid)){
            acc.adderror('You cannot asign this user');
        }        
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I think issue is in your query. SOQL returns List<User> and you are saving it Set<Id>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not assign a value to the set with query. Try the code below :

```
trigger updateOwnerID on Account (after update) {
    set<id> OwnerIds=new Set<id>();
    for (Account acc:trigger.new){
        OwnerIds.add(acc.ownerid);
    }   
    map<id,User> userids=new map<id,User>([select id from user where id in :OwnerIds and NoOwner__c=true]);
    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        if(userids.containsKey(acc.ownerid)){
            acc.adderror('You cannot asign this user');
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SOQL query return List of sObjects instead of set so you need to modify your code in following way

```
trigger updateOwnerID on Account (after update) {
    set<id> OwnerIds=new Set<id>();
    for (Account acc:trigger.new){
        OwnerIds.add(acc.ownerid);
    }   

    //Get list of users in a list and then add to set.
    set<id> userids=new set<id>();
    for(User objUser : [select id from user where id in :OwnerIds and NoOwner__c=true]){

    userids.add(objUser.id);
    }
    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        if(userids.contains(acc.ownerid)){
            acc.adderror('You cannot asign this user');
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to clarify Himanshu.. Can we do this `set<id> userids=new set<id>();
    userids.addAll(usersList);` means can we add the list of user into set of Ids ?

Comment: I think addAll won't work here. Incompatible argument types.

Comment: @Ratan thanks for pointing out. I just overlooked that :) updated

Comment: @Himanshu great now looks good..

Comment: i guess your answer covers mine.so removing it :)